# Sharing photo on facebook using intent Android?

Tags: android, facebook, image, android-intent, twitter

i want to send photo using intent 
i have try this code but my problem is if i use this code for sharing than it open all the applciation related to sharing i want to open only FACEBOOK AND TWITTER APP for sharing

```
Intent sharefacebook = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            sharefacebook.setType("image/*");
            sharefacebook.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From Android");              
            sharefacebook.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+filepath.toString()));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharefacebook, "Sharing"));
```

it open email,skype,gmail everthing i want to open only facebook and twitter it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the client apps(activities) and start the activity only if it's a fb/twitter client like this:

```
   final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
            for (final ResolveInfo info : matches){
                if (info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("facebook") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("twitter")){ 
        Intent sharefacebook = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                    sharefacebook.setType("image/*");
                    sharefacebook.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From Android");              
                    sharefacebook.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+filepath.toString()));                              
                   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharefacebook, "Sharing"));   
            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FB or twitter client not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    }
```